# Download direct messages from Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message

Is there a way I can copy/paste or download old DM's from my iPhone 6? I can not see DM's as far back as I need on my computer.

Comment: The Twitter API might be able to help?

Comment: If your question is about the Twitter iOS app, you're on the wrong site. Questions on Web Apps should only be concerned with the web interface of Twitter.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need specifically to retrieve them using your iPhone or it could be fine on your computer?

You can scroll up as much as you want on your iPhone or your computer to retrieve older tweets without limitations but it may be a bit inconvenient.

I have created a [tool](https://github.com/Mincka/DMArchiver) to download my direct messages, with the ability to also download the uploaded images and GIFs (as MP4).

Because it does not rely on the API, it is possible to download more than 200 messages. The script just simulate the "scrolling method" and parse the result.

The main idea is to make requests in loop by calling the following URL with a valid `auth_token` cookie value for the authentication and parse the json response:
https://twitter.com/messages/with/conversation?id=1337&max_entry_id=1337

The `max_entry_id` value is not required for the first request. You need to use the value of the `min_entry_id` variable in the response as the new `max_entry_id` in each subsequent iteration to get the next 20 older tweets. When `max_entry_id` is not in the json response, you are at the begin of the thread.